# User management in Apache Shiro

Tags: java, security, shiro, user-management

I am starting with Apache Shiro. A database is used for persistence via Shiro's JdbcRealm.

My question is whether Shiro provides some support for user management, such as user creation, assigning them roles, etc. Something like UserDetailsManager/JdbcUserDetailsManager in Spring. Or do I need to modify the underlying DB directly without any Shiro API?

Thanks

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Database Administrators Stack Exchange](http://dba.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Apache shiro provides security to the user for their applications.

you can refer [Apache Shiro Terminology](http://shiro.apache.org/terminology.html) to get more details about the features and terminology in shiro.

It seems there is no any support for managing users to create or delete. You have to implement your own for that.